# How to add foreign key associations in Rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, polymorphic-associations, model-associations

I am setting has_many and belongs_to association in Rails Model: Events(name, identifier, eid) and Users(name, uid)and there is confusion regarding foreign key and primary key. I know what foreign key and primary key means but confused which primary key to use in Events model: eid or uid. I have seen some code on Github where they have added foreign key on User model too. Is it required in my case?

Are migrations required to add these associations?

Given:

1. Each User can have many events.
2. Each event belongs to a single user.
3. Events identifier maps to the user uuid(unique for every user).
4. eid is an unique id for every event.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :events, inverse_of: :user
end

class Event < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :identifier, inverse_of: :events
end
```

Expected Result:

```
user = User.first  
user.events # Lists all events

event = Event.first  
event.user # Outputs first user
```

Comment: Primary_key for users table is `uid` - with it you can identify any user definitely. You need to store its value in the events table, and you store it in the identifier column, if I understood you correctly. So looks like you created the correct structure. Do you have any errors when you run `event.user` in the console?

Comment: @Vasilisa For User.first.events it shows
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'events.user_id' in 'where clause': SELECT  `events`.* FROM `events` WHERE `events`.`user_id` = '238329898'

Comment: Which types have columns 'uid' and 'identifier'?

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that `uid` and `eid` are uuids, not integers?

Comment: Yes, they are uuids. They are of string type. I changed there name here to get a better understanding

Comment: Try `has_many :events, foreign_key: :identifier` - I missed that you defined it only on one side

Comment: Still showing error: ActiveRecord::InverseOfAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the inverse association for user (:event in User)

Comment: Don't remove `inverse_of` in this case

Answer (score 0):

You should use the column in the users table, which uniquely identifies the users. As I read you post that is `uid`, in that case your code should look something like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :events, inverse_of: :event
end

class Events < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :uid, inverse_of: :user
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: So we add fields of other model in foreign_key and primary_key? Shouldn't we mention identifier as foreign_key in User model?